# Remove columns from column chooser

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a `GridView` that contains a list of columns. Some columns I need to have in the grid, some columns I don't use. Those columns are disabled but exist in the column chooser. Is it possible to remove them from the column chooser columns in the `GridView`? For disabling columns I use the following code but it doesn't work:

```
private void HideColumn(GridView grid, string columnName)
{
    grid.Columns[columnName].VisibleIndex = -1;
    grid.Columns[columnName].OptionsColumn.ShowInCustomizationForm = false;
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct. Can you show how you are using your code and how you adding columns to grid?

Comment: Try to update `Column chooser` after disabling a column by this way: `grid.UpdateColumnsCustomization();`.

Comment: @nempoBu4
`this.gridViewParameters.Columns.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn[] {
            this.colAA,
            this.colSelectParameter,
            this.colTest,
            this.colParameterTestId,
            this.colControl,
            this.colParamWorkstation,
            this.colTurnaroundTime,
            this.colATCC,
            this.colFunctionalGroup});`
I add columns to grid in such way

Comment: `gridView.Columns[controlId].Visible = true;
gridView.Columns[atccColumn].Visible = true;
RemoveColumnsFromColumnChooser(colAA, colFunctionalGroup, colQCItemID, colTest);


private void RemoveColumnsFromColumnChooser(params GridColumn[] columns)
        {
            foreach (GridColumn column in columns)
            {
                if (gridViewParameters.Columns.Contains(column))
                {
                    HideColumn(gridViewParameters, column.FieldName);
                }
            }
            gridViewParameters.UpdateColumnsCustomization();
        }`
Code usage

Comment: When you are disabling the columns your `Column chooser` is opened?

Comment: No, `Column chooser` is closed when I disabled columns.

Comment: It seems that you are using the same `GridColumn` objects for two grids (`gridView` and `gridViewParameters`). You must create another columns for `gridViewParameters`.

Comment: `gridView` is only name of local variable. 'gridView' has the same meaning that `gridViewParameters`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Can you add a sample code to your question that can be reproduced?

Comment: @nempoBu4 I cannot provide sample of code because code structure of my project has a very difficult structure. I noticed when I open `Column chooser` at first - redundant columns are presented, but when I close `Column chooser` and re-open it - columns are absent. I guess it related to refreshing data in `GridView` or in `Customization form`. Could you say any words on this?

Comment: There is only the [`GridView.UpdateColumnsCustomization`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_UpdateColumnsCustomizationtopic) method for updating `Column chooser`.

Comment: Try to use `GridView.UpdateColumnsCustomization` method in [`GridView.ShowCustomizationForm`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_ShowCustomizationFormtopic) event.